# Static library compiled with Visual C++ is compatible with a higher version of Visual C++?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I have compiled a static library with Visual C++ Express 2010. This library can be used for example with Visual Studio 2013 (using C++)?

Comment: Maybe.  Odds are pretty low, C++11 has caused rather massive changes in the standard C++ library.  You of course find out by trying this, if you get linker errors then it is a definite no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, no. A static library can only be used with a project that's built using the same compiler version and substantially the same settings. For example, even when using the same VC version, you can't combine a library built with Debug configuration and another module built with Release, or vice versa.

Since you say you've compiled the library, this means you have source code for it. Why not just rebuild it with VC2013?

Comment: What about when I compile a dll?

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21885909/how-to-make-libraries-independent-to-compiler-version/21888708) helps

Answer (score 1):

This has since changed: binaries built using Visual Studio 2015 or newer can be used in any Visual Studio release that is more recent. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=msvc-170